# Android Emulator showing error after installing API 26

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My android studio is showing an error after I tried to use an AVD with API 26. The error message is

> Error while waiting for the device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_S_API_24 was killed.

Earlier Nexus S with API 24 used to run with charm but it is showing the same error since yesterday after I installed API 26 and tried it with Nexus 5x API 26. I have asked this question on several forums and even tried a lot of things like changing the Graphics to Software in AVD manager. I even tried to reinstall it but the problem is still there.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it as follows:

Go to: Tools > Android > AVD Manager
Press the "edit" (pencil) icon next to your AVD
Change "Graphics" to "Software".

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Files -> Settings -> Android SDK - > Uncheck emulator (HAXM) - > apply -> check it again -> apply*

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely something with with your graphics card driver, check and see if you have the latest version installed.

For linux flatpak users of android studio, make sure to run "flatpak update", if the flatpak gpu libraries do not match with your system driver, then this issue will popup.

Answer (score 0):

The Hardware to Software trick works only with non Play Store Emulators

How it fixed for me is :

1. Uninstall all AVDs>Delete from location>Uninstall
2. ReInstall HAXM from SDK Tools

Also select the boot type as Cold Boot by going to to AVD manager>Edit>Additional Settings>Boottype>Cold Boot.